# get the exact match and the total number of keywords

Tags: sphinx

Is it possible to get the exact match of the keywords based the number of them? Below is more clear I guess :)

```
In index I have this 
record 1 "This is text"
record 2 "This is text and text"
```

then when I search for "This is text" I need to find only the first record.

Please note that I tried many filter but none seems to work, I always get both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extended match mode query of

```
"^this is test$"
```

should do it. Read up on the field-start, field-end and phrase operators for more inforation